# Yii 2 module, access USER class

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I am creating a Yii 2 based module and i have to access the users table within this module. 
And i want to make it as abstract as possible so:

Is it possible to do something like

```
Yii::$app->user->findOne();
```

within the module?

Or do i have to hardcode the User identification class and make note that it has to be changed for every new system the module will be in?

Or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why you want to do this? `Yii::$app->user->findOne();` if you need current user data you have it in `Yii::$app->user->identity`. For other things make model for users table, import it and use.

Comment: Thats the thing.. I have to find one user other than the user that is logged in and i am doing this in a module. So i want to link to User table abstractly, if somone changes the User Model.... i dont want to hardcode use bla/bla/UserModel.php.

Comment: Why you don't want to hardcode it in use? You can get className for identity by calling `\Yii::$app->user->identityClass` if you don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: You can use this code `$class = \Yii::$app->user->identityClass;$identity = $class::findIdentity(1);` to achieve this goal. Just tested - it works. Or with `call_user_func()`.

Comment: Or there is even 1 more way. I think it's not so dirty as previous. Move userClassName to application config for your module and use it.